# How to get processor unique identifier?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to get processor unique id?

Like this (BFEBFBFF000406E3). I get this id with software Get Cpu Id 2014.

```
int main()
{

    BYTE szCpu[16] = { 0 };
    UINT uCpuID = 0U;
    _asm
        {
            mov eax, 0
                cpuid
                mov dword ptr szCpu[0], ebx
                mov dword ptr szCpu[4], edx
                mov dword ptr szCpu[8], ecx
                mov eax, 1
                cpuid
                mov uCpuID, edx
        }
    cout << szCpu << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

This code give me output GenuineIntel. Any help?

Comment: what property name does the software describe this unique id(BFEBFBFF000406E3) ?

Comment: What you mean ?

Comment: It maybe a combination or the result of a specific calculation of some cpu information

Comment: Which cpu information combination?

Comment: I'm voting to close because I can't understand from the question what the requested field is.

Comment: @Mikhail You got a eyes problem. Did you see this (get processor unique id?)

Comment: Solution: This is the "ProcessorId" from CIM/WMI. You can get it like this: Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Processor | select ProcessorId